# How to remove toolbar ToolBarItem() from a view (SwiftUI)

Tags: swiftui

When adding ToolBarItem's to my top navigation bar and I navigate to another view (via a tabbar at the bottom) - the ToolBarItem's from the previous view are still visible.  Is it possible to reset the ToolBarItems or Navigation Toolbar for the 2nd view?

ContentView() I have

```
TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
    Home()
         .tabItem {
              Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                   .foregroundColor(.primary)
         }
         .tag("Home")
                
     Other()
         .tabItem {
              Label("Other", systemImage: "heart)
                   .foregroundColor(.primary)
         }
         .tag("Other")
}
```

Inside Home() I have

```
.toolbar {
   ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
      Image(systemName: "gearshape")
   }
}
```

When I navigate to Other() the toolbar from Home() is still shown.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `HomeView` you should add a `NavigationView` or `NavigationStack` and modifier your code as follows to achieve the desired effect:

```
struct Home: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            //Your view here
        }
    }
}
```

What is different:

- `NavigationView` provides a navigation bar for its child views. When you embed your view inside a NavigationView, you're enabling the display of the navigation bar and toolbar items.
- If you don't use the `NavigationView` and still have the `toolbar` in the `HomeView`. That means the toolbar item with the gear icon is added directly to the `TabView`. This way, the toolbar item will be displayed consistently across all tabs.